# For "fine-tuning", does the "domain adaptation" approach make sense?

Tags: neural-networks, object-detection, transfer-learning, domain-adaptation

I understand "domain adaptation" to be a type of "transfer-learning" technique.

Domain Adaptation:
By applying knowledge obtained from a domain with sufficient teacher labels (Source Domain) to a target domain without sufficient information (Target Domain), a discriminator, etc. that works with high accuracy in the target domain is learned.
(Domain is a term that refers to a collection of data.)

Can I use the "domain adaptation" approach for "fine-tuning" in object detection tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Fine-tuning is basically one very heuristic approach to doing domain adaptation. In particular, it's an (again, very heuristic) way to do *supervised* domain adaptation, i.e., where you have labeled data from the target domain. (There are also many *unsupervised* domain adaptation approaches.)

You may find [these slides](http://imatge-upc.github.io/telecombcn-2016-dlcv/slides/D2L5-transfer.pdf) or this [introduction to transfer learning and domain adaptation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.11806.pdf) helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For example, I want to train a model to detect Personal Protective Equipment (PPE). However, there are many different types of hardhats, gloves, and safety harnesses, plus a variety of workwear looks. It would be difficult to collect a large amount of diverse labeled data. In this case, I would collect a large amount of data and do labelling (or annotation). Should I then "transfer learning"? Could you give me some advice?